# Solved: Layered Navigation of Parent Categories

Tags: magento2, category, xml, layered-navigation, filter

The layered navigation of the Child Categories it's working okay. The problem is with Parent Categories.

I'm trying to have the same filters on Parent Categories but i still can't solve it.

What I need on Parent Category Filter:

- Shop by Color
- Shop by Price
- Shop by Material

What it's displaying now:

- Shop by Category

On Child Categories it's been displaying okay.

Comment: Make sure that "is Anchor" is set to yes in the parent category, here is the Magento user guide for layered navigation -> https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/navigation-layered-filterable-attributes.html